# How to get my Chrome window back to a state where the resize function works normally?

Tags: google-chrome

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Chrome 31.0.1650.63. Somehow my Chrome browser window has gotten into a state where it behaves different from before and different from any other window that I have ever experienced. On this Chrome window, when I drag a side to change the size of the window then the opposite side is resized at the same time in the opposite direction. When I drag a corner to move two sides then both opposite sides are also moved (in the opposite direction, so the window maintains the position of its center). Shutdown and restart of the computer did not remove the problem. How do I change things back to the state where dragging one side or one corner affects only that side or corner?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, but in my case resize and maximize where disabled, I couldn't drag the window either. When I tried using the mouse to resize it nothing happened and the chrome window was covering the whole screen and I wasn't able to "restore" or maximize. Even when I tried using the context menu with CTRL+space, resize and maximize options were disabled.

What I did was open a new tab (CTRL+T) and then drag that new tab down so that chrome creates a new windows. The new window had all the options I wanted enabled and I could drag that new window around. I closed the other one, and when I start chrome again everything works fine.

I hope this can help in your case.